# Separating a tree Regression Model based on unique values of one column

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a data set of 20,000,000 rows. Each row has 30 columns.

One of the columns contains 7000 unique Product Numbers.

Each row contains a Unit Cost value that I would like to predict using all the columns other than the Unit Cost.

I would like to build a unique decision tree or a unique branch of a decision tree to model the data for each Product Number.

Basically partitioning the rows for each Product Number and modelling each Product Number in isolation.

I would like to train a single model in Azure to do this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use create R module with a train script using lapply to create multiple models

training script is something like below:

```
model <-
  lapply(seq(max(dataset$ProductNumber)),
               function(j)
                    if(nrow(dataset[dataset$ProductNumber==j,])>0)
                    {
                      multinom(UnitCost~.,data=dataset[dataset$ProductNumber==j,])
                    }


         )
```

Then you can use predictive  script something like below

```
probabilities <- predict(model[[dataset$ProductNumber]], dataset, type="probs")
scores<-data.frame(probabilities)
```